# Railscasts Not Working - 147 and 302

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I tried implementing the features in RailsCast [147 Sortable Lists](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists) and [302 In-Place Editing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing), but after having followed every step along the way, the effects that showed on Ryan's screen was different from mine.

In the case of [302 In-Place Editing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing), clicking on the supposedly in-place-editing-enabled text had no effects!

I had simple code to implement the best_in_place in views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>

<% firstname = @user.name.split(" ")[0] %>
<p>
    <%= best_in_place @user, :email %>
</p>
```

And in the case of [147 Sortable Lists](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists), the line `<%= sortable_element("faq") %>` gave me an `undefined method 'sortable_element'` error.

Please help!

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  That sortable_element method seems to have been removed somewhere in 3.0.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, any idea how I can get the in-line-editing to work?

Comment: Ryan usually provides source code downloads for his RailsCasts. I would suggest you download the accompanying source code and compare your code with his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to diagnose the issue without seeing the code that doesn't behave as expected for the first part of your question.

[`sortable_element`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ScriptaculousHelper/sortable_element) was deprecated in Rails 3.0.9, which explains the second issue.

Comment: I updated my code in view. What wouldbe a Rails > 3.0.9 way of doing the sortable list then?